# map view model to object in domain using Auto Mapper

Tags: automapper

```cs
public class Department
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Department department { get; set; }
}

public class vmEmployeeDepartment
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map vmEmployeeDepartment to Empolyee

```cs
public JsonResult Add(vmMuasher vm)
{
    var model = Mapper.Map<vmEmployeeDepartment, Empolyee>(vm);
    _EmployeeService.Add(model);

    return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The problem is : Department object inside Emplyee domain is null,

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not enough info. What's the content of `vm`? How did you configure AutoMapper? Please edit your question to add the missing parts.

Comment: Configuration in the start up file: 

 Mapper.Initialize(config =>

    {
          config.CreateMap<Employee, vmEmployeeDepartment>();
          config.CreateMap<vmEmployeeDepartment, Employee>();
    });

Comment: public class vm
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

Comment: AutoMapper is able to flatten a mapping. Not to deepen it. You better do that manually.